# How to handle click event and append HTML in Lit-Element?

Tags: polymer, web-component, lit-element, lit

- Trying to create a list using every button click.
- I want to append the li tag in the ul element. OnClick I have created the addList function.
- Handle click event.

  Here is the code.

```
render() {
    return html`
    <input oninput="${this.getNewVal}" id="name" type="text" value="${this.name}">
    <button onclick="${this._addList}" type="button">Add</button>
    <p class=${classMap(this.classes)} style=${styleMap(this.styles)}>Hello, ${this.name}!</p>
    <ul></ul>
    `;
  }

function addList(){
    this.listItems.push(this.name);
}
```

Comment: Hiten, For better understanding of your query or errors please share your code.

Answer (score 2):

What you basically need to do is:

1. Have an array where you store the items of your list
2. Add new elements to said array when the button is clicked
3. Render the list using either the `map` function of the array of the `repeat` directive (depending on whether you will be reordering said items or not one might be more efficient than the other)

Here's an example of how that would look like (taken from the [lit.dev tutorial](https://lit.dev/tutorial/#06-template-logic))

```js
import {LitElement, html} from 'lit';

class ToDoList extends LitElement {
  static properties = {
    listItems: {},
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.listItems = [
      {text: 'Start Lit tutorial', completed: true},
      {text: 'Make to-do list', completed: false},
    ];
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <h2>To Do</h2>
      <ul>
        ${this.listItems.map((item) => html`<li>${item.text}</li>`)}
      </ul>
      <input id="newitem" aria-label="New item">
      <button @click=${this.addToDo}>Add</button>
    `;
  }

  get input() {
    return this.renderRoot?.querySelector('#newitem') ?? null;
  }

  addToDo() {
    this.listItems.push({text: this.input.value, completed: false});
    this.input.value = '';
    this.requestUpdate();
  }
}
customElements.define('todo-list', ToDoList);
```

You might want to take a look at [the template section](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/lists/) of the lit docs or just do the [tutorial](https://lit.dev/tutorial/#06-template-logic) I mentioned above